# Fill HTML Form and get result of a javascript function iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, html, forms, fill

I had searched in any way to resolve my problem but nothing!

I have this web page with this field:

```
<form method="post" name="form_verifica" action="popup.jsp">
<input name="cod" type="text"  >
<td id="code" name="code" >
<input name="conc" type="text" >
<input src="" onclick="return checkcode();"  type="image">
```

How can I fill "cod" and "conc" field and then Call checkcode() function?
I Have tried this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"MioURL/popup.jsp"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithString: Codice.text] forKey:@"cod"];
    [request setPostValue:[NSString stringWithString: Concorso.text] forKey:@"conc"];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

What i wrong?

Apologize me for my bad english.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, give the input elements ids, and then load their values something like this:

```
NSString *myFieldValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('myField').value;"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but I don't only retrieve a field from this page ...I should fill "cod" and "conc" fields in [this page](http://servizi.sisal.it/verificavincite/popup.jsp) page and than execute checkcode() function that return me another page with my interesting info...Thank you

Comment: i want to pass a value to [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"document.getElementById('myField').value;"] .How to do it ?